# Does the auto generated query to list a type by Appsync always do a full table scan?

Tags: aws-appsync, aws-appsync-resolver

I have this type that I've defined below. And appsync will build out the query to retrieve a list. When I look in dynamodb the id is the primary key. So is it me or is this extremely inefficient as it would have to scan the entire table to find all rows with the owner column equal to the logged in user because the owner column that is auto generated is not a key?

```
type PurchasedPackage @model @auth(rules: [{ allow: owner }]) {
  id: ID!
  purchaseOrder: String!
  subscriptionPackage: PackageType!
}

query MyQuery {
  listPurchasedPackages {
    items {
      createdAt
      id
      owner
      purchaseOrder
      subscriptionPackage
      updatedAt
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle this situation:

1. You Can Override the AutoGenerated ID and used your "owner" as PK.
2. You can use GSI to handle this situation.